# Performing searches on JSON data in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash

I have mapped JSON data into Elasticsearch via Logstash which has worked, it has imported the data in and I can see it in Elasticsearch-Head.

My problem is querying the data. I can run a search for a field but it returns the entire type within the index as a single search result. I have tried a few variations but have not had any luck.

Here is the logstash shipper file:

```
input {
   exec {
     type => "recom_db"
     command => "curl -s -X GET http://www.test.com/api/edselastic/recom_db.json"
     interval => 86400
     codec => "json"
   }
   exec {
     type => "recom_ki"
     command => "curl -s -X GET http://www.test.com/api/edselastic/recom_ki.json"
     interval => 86400
     codec => "json"
   }
   exec {
     type => "recom_un"
     command => "curl -s -X GET http://www.test.com/api/edselastic/recom_un.json"
     interval => 86400
     codec => "json"
   }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
                host => localhost
                index => "lib-recommender-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
                template_name => "recommender-template"
        }
}
```

and the Elasticsearch index is in the following form:

```
{
    "_index": "lib-recommender-2015.06.11",
    "_type": "recom_un",
    "_id": "qoZE4aF-SkS--tq_8MhH4A",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "item": [{
            "name": "AAM219 -- reading lists",
            "link": "http://www.test.com/modules/aam219.html",
            "description": "AAM219 -- reading lists",
            "terms": {
                "term": ["AAM219"]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "AAR410 -- reading lists",
            "link": "http://www.test.com/modules/aar410.html",
            "description": "AAR410 -- reading lists",
            "terms": {
                "term": ["AAR410"]
            }
        }
        ...
```

Anyway so I have tried querying the data the various ways I have seen in the Elasticsearch documentation but am unable to a desired result. Here is one of the many queries I have tried:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/lib-recommender/recom_un/_search" -d'
{
    "fields": ["item.name", "item.link"],
    "query":{
        "term": {
                "item.terms.term": "AAM219"
                        }
                }
        }
}'
```

but it returns the entire type within the index (with the correct fields selected but disjointed and all of them):

```
{
    "took": 13,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.006780553,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "lib-recommender-2015.06.11",
            "_type": "recom_un",
            "_id": "qoZE4aF-SkS--tq_8MhH4A",
            "_score": 0.006780553,
            "fields": {
                "item.link": ["http://www.test.com/modules/aam219.html",
                "http://www.test.com/modules/aar410.html",
                "http://www.test.com/modules/ac1201.html",
                "http://www.test.com/modules/aca401.html",
```

I am after the following result:

```
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.006780553,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "lib-recommender-2015.06.11",
            "_type": "recom_un",
            "_id": "qoZE4aF-SkS--tq_8MhH4A",
            "_score": 0.006780553,
            "_source": {
                "item": [{
                    "name": "AAM219 -- reading lists",
                    "link": "http://www.test.com/modules/aam219.html",
                    "description": "AAM219 -- reading lists",
                    "terms": {
                        "term": ["AAM219"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Is the mapping of the index wrong for this kind of search (so should I manually make a mapping file for elasticsearch before importing data). Is there a parameter I am missing in the query? I have been looking for an answer but feel like I am running around in circles now, I am guessing it is something simple that I am overlooking but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to Val's answer above. It was mostly what but with another level of nesting.
Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "recom_un": {
    "properties": {
      "item": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "link": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "terms": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "term": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search query I used to get what I wanted:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/lib-recommender/recom_un/_search" -d'
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "item",
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "item.terms",
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "term": "AAM219"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "inner_hits": { }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for this kind of use case to work you need to create a custom mapping and make sure your `item` structure is of type [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) otherwise all the fields in your `item` will be collapsed together as you saw in the results you showed.

So the mapping needs to be like this:

```
{
  "recom_un": {
    "properties": {
      "item": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "link": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "terms": {
            "properties": {
              "term": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can modify your query a bit to use a [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) instead like this. Also note I'm including the [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) so your results only include the matching nested document:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/lib-recommender/recom_un/_search" -d'
{
  "fields": [
    "item.name",
    "item.link"
  ],
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "item",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "item.terms.term": "AAM219"
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I have tried that but am now getting no results. I have double checked the mapping and template and the "item" objects now have the "type": "nested" parameter. Is there anything else I can try or could I have a configuration issue perhaps?

Comment: Is `item` the only property of your document or are there others? In the former case, why not simply indexing each single item as a standalone document so you could get rid of the nested type altogether?

Comment: Yes you are right about indexing of `item`, it will be the only property. I wanted to do a nested search without changing the data much as I will have to search nested data anyway (`item.terms.term for example`). For the record your answer above is correct but i needed to change the `"term"` to `"match"`. Your way would work if I had the index for the field set to `"not_analyzed"`.

Comment: Actually I needed to set the nested type for `terms` also. I will post the full solution I have below to help guide other people who have the same issue in future. Thanks Val for pointing me in the right direction.